# Cannot commit on Subversion using Xcode 4

Tags: iphone, xcode, svn, ipad, xcode4

I would know how can I solve this issue when I try to commit a file:

> The working copy "PROJECT-NAME" failed
>   to commit files.
>
> dyld: lazy symbol binding failed:
>   Symbol not found: _apr_stat$INODE64
>   Referenced from: /usr/bin/svn
>   Expected in: /usr/lib/libapr-1.0.dylib
>
> dyld: Symbol not found:
>   _apr_stat$INODE64   Referenced from: /usr/bin/svn   Expected in:
>   /usr/lib/libapr-1.0.dylib

I can list, checkout but I can't commit with Xcode.
I can use Versions or command line to commit. But I would like to be able to commit with Xcode too.

So I tried to change the dynamic library libapr-1.0 to a more recent library with this command from the shell:

```
sudo install_name_tool -change /usr/lib/libapr-1.0.dylib /usr/lib/libapr-1.0.3.8.dylib /usr/bin/svn
```

It appears Xcode won't list anymore, so what should I do? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your 'svn' binary is broken.

You can update it to newest version by downloading and compiling source code of svn. There is really easy guide on apple.com:
http://developer.apple.com/tools/subversionxcode.html
(just skip to "Installing Subversion" section).

You can also ask someone to send you compiled binary.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following:

1. Install/reinstall the latest version of svn
2. If that doesn't work, reinstall Xcode